# Do-while acting funny in my basic singly linked list implementation in C. Please identify the error

Tags: c, linked-list

The implementation is fine. No compile errors, everything works. It's just that it seems like the do-while costruct repeats itself twice when it shouldn't. For example, when if choose "i" for "insert a new node", the case should switch to 'i', call the insert function, and then traverse the list. It DOES do that, but also prints everything in the do-while loop again and prints the default case.

I'll post the code followed an output of my code.

Here's my code in C that implements a linked list and it's basic traversal and insertion functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void traverse(struct node *);
void insert(struct node **);

int main()
{
    char choice;
    struct node *head,**tohead;
    head=(struct node *)malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    tohead=&head;
    //STACKOVERFLOW NOTE: this is where I think the relevant portion begins
    do
    {
        printf("\nChoose operation to perform:\n");
        printf("\tInsert a node(i)\n");
        printf("\tShow currenct linked list(s)\n");
        printf("\tQuit without saving changes(q):\t");
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'i':
                insert(tohead);
                break;
            case 's':
                traverse(head);
                break;
            case 'q':
                printf("QUITTING\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice\n");
        }
    }while(choice!='q');
}//STACKOVERFLOW NOTE: This is where I think relevant portion ends. Possibly.

void traverse(struct node *p)
{
    printf("Linked list looks like: ");

    if(p->next==0)
    {
        printf("nothing. It's EMPTY");
        p->next==NULL;
    }
    else
    {   while(p->next!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\t",p->data);
            p=p->next;
        }
        printf("%d",p->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void insert(struct node **pp)
{
    int value,position;
    struct node *q;
    q=*pp;
    struct node *newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Insert what number?:\t");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    printf("In what position? Push '0' for last,'1' for first");
    printf("\n\t\tOR\nenter position no.:\t");
    scanf("%d",&position);
    newnode->data=value;
    if(position==1)
    {   newnode->next=q;
        *pp=newnode;
    }
    else if(position==0)
    {
        while(q->next!=NULL)
            q=q->next;
        q->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=NULL;
    }
    else if(position>1)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<position-1;i++)
            q=q->next;
        newnode->next=q->next;
        q->next=newnode;
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid Position");
    traverse(*pp);
}
```

Here's a sample output: Notice how the do-while repeats itself and says 'Invalid choice'

user@host:~$ ./a.out

```
Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): i
Insert what number?:    5
In what position? Push '0' for last,'1' for first
        OR
enter position no.: 0
Linked list looks like: 0   5

Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): Invalid choice

Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): i
Insert what number?:    3
In what position? Push '0' for last,'1' for first
        OR
enter position no.: 1
Linked list looks like: 3   0   5

Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): Invalid choice

Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): i
Insert what number?:    2
In what position? Push '0' for last,'1' for first
        OR
enter position no.: 3
Linked list looks like: 3   0   2   5

Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): Invalid choice

Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): s
Linked list looks like: 3   0   2   5

Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): Invalid choice

Choose operation to perform:
    Insert a node(i)
    Show currenct linked list(s)
    Quit without saving changes(q): q
QUITTING
user@host:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter anything for input with `Scanf`, you end it with a newline. The problem is that the `scanf` function only extracts the input requested, and leaves the newline in the input buffer, so in the next iteration the program reads and extracts that newline and sees it as invalid input and loops once again.

This is very easy to solve: Add an extra space before the `"%c"` format code, so it's

```
scanf(" %c",&choice);
/*     ^           */
/*     |           */
/* Note space here */
```

This will tell `scanf` to read and *discard* all leading white-space (which newline is).

I also recommend you to read e.g [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).